# Compare items in a list to other multiple nested lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I have multiple lists, each nested, with the format below :

```
listA = [['A', '17']
         ['A', '16']
         ['A', '15']]
```

I want to compare one list (let's say listA), with "any" number of other lists, to get second element matches that listA and all other lists have in common, an example:

comparing listA with listB and listC:

```
listB = [['B', '17'],
         ['B', '12'],
         ['B', '11']]

listC = [['A', '18'],
         ['A', '17'],
         ['A', '15']]
```

the only match between all lists here is "17" so the result should be:

```
new_list_A = [['A', '17']]
new_list_B = [['B', '17']]
new_list_C = [['C', '17']]
```

what is the best approach here, and what is the most pythonic solution?

Comment: what have  you tried?

Comment: I don't understand how the output is generated. Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Make `set`s with 2nd elements. Then get the `intersection`. Then run through the lists and keep only those which's 2nd element is in the intersection.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, the function has to compare all second elements of all given lists, if they are the same, it should append results to new lists.

Comment: ...but what have you tried?

Comment: @user4343502 i tried set().intersection() but with my knowledge , i can't make it work.
i also tried to make a seperate list for list[1] values but its not efficient and its slow

Comment: @user4343502 list comprehension with set() & is not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the intersection set of all of the second elements. Then return all elements from each list where the second element is in the intersection set.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

listA = [['A', '17'],
         ['A', '16'],
         ['A', '15']]

listB = [['B', '17'],
         ['B', '12'],
         ['B', '11']]

listC = [['C', '18'],
         ['C', '17'],
         ['C', '15']]

lists = [listA, listB, listC]


def to_set(a_list):
    return {b for _, b in a_list}


intersection = to_set(lists[0])
for a_set in (to_set(a_list) for a_list in lists[1:]):
    intersection = intersection & a_set


flattened_lists = (item
                   for a_list in lists
                   for item in a_list)
results = [item
           for item in flattened_lists
           if item[1] in intersection]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there a way to make this compatible with an unknown number of lists?

Comment: done. Also converted to using generators for space and time.

Comment: than you very much, I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
>>> listA = [['A', '17'],
         ['A', '16'],
         ['A', '15']]
>>> listB = [['B', '17'],
         ['B', '12'],
         ['B', '11']]
>>> listC = [['A', '18'],
         ['A', '17'],
         ['A', '15']]

>>> set_maker = lambda l: set(x[1] for x in l)
>>> set_a = set_maker(listA)
>>> set_b = set_maker(listB)
>>> set_c = set_maker(listC)
>>> common_items = set_a.intersection(set_b, set_c)
>>> list_filter = lambda l: [x for x in l if x[1] in common_items]
>>> result_list_A = list_filter(listA)
>>> result_list_B = list_filter(listB)
>>> result_list_C = list_filter(listC)
>>> result_list_A
[['A', '17']]
>>> result_list_B
[['B', '17']]
>>> result_list_C
[['A', '17']]
```